# Need to align menu buttons properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, text-alignment

I'm having trouble aligning menu buttons properly.

How do I move up a button into the white space above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative `margin-top` value on the `span` holding it,